# ngrx chaining Http requests in effects

Tags: javascript, rxjs, ngrx

I have some issues regarding to my code in a ngrx Effect. I want to chain two http calls, but for some reasons, my stream is blocked during the second http call.

Here is my code:

```
@Effect()
appointmentAvailable$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
  .ofType(actions.ActionTypes.MY_ACTION).map((action) => {
    return action.payload;
  }).flatMap((request: A) => {
      const temp = this.service1.remotehttp(request).map(
        response => Object.assign({}, request, { field: response[0].field }))
      console.log('service 1 answered');
      return temp;
  })
  .flatMap((request: A) => {
      console.log('service 2' + JSON.stringify(request));
      const t = this.service2.remotehttp(request);
      console.log('service 2 answered');
      return t;
  })
  .map((res) => {
      return new actions.MyActionComplete(res);
  }).catch((error) => {
      return Observable.of(new actions.MyActionError(error));
  });
```

Here is my console:

```
service 1 called
service 2 {"field":correctValue, ....}
```

and no 'service 2 answered'

I really don't know what's wrong in my code, do someone has a clue ?

Comment: have you tried to concatenate the the second flatMap and the map/catch to temp?

Comment: Have you tried mergeMap instead of flatMap?

Comment: @Zycho 1) check this.. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/333 2) Then look at collection.ts in the example linked here https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/master/src/app/effects/collection.ts

Comment: @MattSugden flatMap is an alias for mergeMap.